# Firebase Crashlytics do not show any issues on portal

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, crashlytics

We have the application completely set up and even got the confirmation on the console that a crash report has been submitted:

```
2018-01-04 13:16:35.165387-0600 App [14014:1206758] [Crashlytics:Crash] report submission successful
```

However we do not see any issues on the Firebase portal, sometimes we get a notification on the top-right corner:

```
There was an error fetching your Crashlytics app state
```

Is anyone here having the same issue? What can we do to solve this?
Thanks!

Comment: Hmmm weird. Any chance you can share your bundle ID so I can check our backend?

Comment: Thanks! It looks like your app hasn't been fully onboarded. It typically gets onboarded after a build and run event. Can you share the full console output when you run your app without a crash?

Comment: That's right. the thing is that we did it several times. I'm including the console output on the following [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fq29pgqeqn5dceh/Futura_Log.txt?dl=0)

Comment: And, this is the console output of a startup after a crash -> [Link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kutr1nx65efopvi/Futura_Log_Crash.txt?dl=0)

Comment: Can you enable debug mode, run your app again, and then share out the console? https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/force-a-crash#enable_crashlytics_debug_mode

Comment: That both were with debug mode on, I'm including another one just in case. Thanks for your help!  [Console](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ilyfld38ul2dt74/Futura_Log_2.txt?dl=0)

Comment: I'm not seeing all of the output that I'd expect. Is your app connect through a network that uses a proxy or firewall?

Comment: No, nothing at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the issue was happening because the App *Bundle Identifier* specified on the Target settings is different from the App Bundle on the GoogleService-Info.plist

When we change the Bundle Id on the Target settings to the one on the Google´s plist file, the service starts listening for crashes.